# Adobe Analytics Phonegap Plugin: Uncaught type error

Tags: android, cordova, adobe-analytics

I have created an Android project using PhoneGap and after adding the Adobe analytics plugin using the command:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services
```

I'm facing the following errors

1) Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js". index.html:41

2) Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js". cordova.js:955
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trackState' of undefined index.html:46

3) Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js". cordova.js:1688

4) Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js". cordova.js:1688

5) Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.adobe.ADBMobile/sdks/Cordova/ADBMobile/Shared/ADB_Helper.js". cordova.js:1688

The trackAction call on click of links is working fine however the trackState calls fail on every screen load.

Comment: Did you found any solution?